# Random number generation between 0-1 to fill container

Tags: c++, random

I've started learning about modern C++ recently and I've been wondering. I know that I can create pseud-random numbers with a Mersenne Twister this way:

```
std::random_device rnd;
std::mt19937 gen(rnd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(0.,1.);
```

So I've found the algorithm `std::generate(iterator, iterator, generator)` so, my question is. Is there any way to generate random numbers between 0 and 1 with this method and fill the container?

Until now, I've found that if I put for example:

```
std::generate(v.begin(),v.end(),std::rand); // i know rand() is crap
std::generate(v.begin(),v.end(),gen);
```

These two work fine but numbers between 0. and 1. would be real nice for no specific reason.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the distribution in `std::generate` directly, as it's `operator()` requires arguments. However, you can bundle the generator and distribution in a lambda and use that instead.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rnd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rnd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(0.,1.);

    std::vector<double> data(20);

    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), [&gen, &dist]() { return dist(gen); });
}
```

Comment: Sorry I mistyped. I don't use std::gen, I use gen. Sorry. I'll edit it.

Comment: And of course. Thank you for the quick and GREAT answer.

Answer (score -2):

Something along the following lines should work:

```
std::generate(v.begin(),v.end(), [] () { return 1.0*std::rand()/RAND_MAX;});
```

See it working at http://ideone.com/vtHK1l.